# TextField inputProps={{ maxLength: 50 }} выдает ошибку

Tags: next.js, reactjs

есть задача: сократить количество символов в теге до 50, что я и попытался сделать, использовав параметр:
inputProps={{ maxLength: 50 }}. получилось что-то такое [image: часть кода]

но в итоге при попытке вписать в поле что либо вылетает ошибка cannot read property 'focus' of null

в целом я смог нагуглить такой вариант где TextField оборачивается `<div ref={params.InputProps.ref}> <input style={{ width: 200 }} type="text" {...params.inputProps} /> </div>` примерно таким образом, но в таком случае поле схлоповается, игнорируя стили, но все работает. что тут не так может быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему прокидыванием ...params.inputProps в inputProps [image: Часть кода]